# Finding a free port with a python component in Redhawk

Tags: python, eclipse, redhawksdr

I'm currently working on a project that requires I edit a configure file to replace an old standard port number if the port is being used. The code I'm currently using is the following:

```
import os
import sys
import socket
import select
import tempfile
import subprocess
import threading
import Queue
import time
import fileinput
```

...

```
def find_open_port():
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("",0))
s.listen(1)
tempport = s.getsocketname()[1]
s.close()
return tempport
```

When I run it from my Ubuntu machine (Python 2.7.6) , it runs fine, but on my CentOS 6 VM running in my Redhawk Component I get the following:

AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'getsocketname'

Not exactly sure why I'm getting this error. Python in Redhawk is running 2.6 I want to say?
Any clue as to why this would happen and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code calls the method getsockname but your error says getsock**et**name, you sure you copied it right when writing it to Redhawk?

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much haha. I've been sitting here staring at it for over an hour trying to figure out what was wrong! Thank you!